# passing a shared_ptr to this to an object owning a reference

Tags: c++, reference, shared-ptr, circular-dependency

The `SharedEditor` class owns a reference to an object of the `NetworkServer` class whereas the `NetworkServer` objects owns a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SharedEditor>>` of `editors`. In the `SharedEditor` constructor, the `server.connect()` method is called to save the its reference, in the `server.connect()` instead a shared pointer to that editor is saved into the `server`.
The program compile and execute but it badly terminate.

`NetworkServer.h`

```
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include "SharedEditor.h"
#include "Message.h"

class NetworkServer {
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SharedEditor>> editors;
    std::deque<Message> messages;

public:
    int connect(std::shared_ptr<SharedEditor> sharedEditor);
};
```

`NetworkServer.cpp`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include "NetworkServer.h"

static int id = 0;

int NetworkServer::connect(std::shared_ptr<SharedEditor> sharedEditor) {
    editors.push_back(sharedEditor);
    return id++;
}
```

`SharedEditor.h`

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include "Symbol.h"

class NetworkServer;

class SharedEditor {
private:
    NetworkServer& _server;

public:

    SharedEditor(NetworkServer &server);

};
```

`SharedEditor.cpp`

```
#include <exception>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include "SharedEditor.h"
#include "NetworkServer.h"

SharedEditor::SharedEditor(NetworkServer &server)
        : _server(server), _counter(0), base(32), boundary(10) {
    _siteId = server.connect(std::shared_ptr<SharedEditor>(this));
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "NetworkServer.h"

int main() {
    NetworkServer network;
    SharedEditor ed1(network);
    SharedEditor ed2(network);


    return 0;
}
```

It returns with  `-1073740940 (0xC0000374)`

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood how smart pointers work.

```
server.connect(std::shared_ptr<SharedEditor>(this))
```

You pass the pointer `this` to the object allocated on the stack. You must pass only pointers to dynamically allocated objects on the memory heap.

You should do something like below, but your classes are poorly designed, since it is not clear from the semantics that `network` will own newly allocated object.

```
SharedEditor* ed1 = new SharedEditor(network);
```

Comment: "but this code is poorly designed, since it is not clear from the semantics that network will own newly allocated object." can you clarify this point? Are you referring to my code design?

Comment: This stack exchange site is for technical questions. To discuss your design please post your question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: **You must pass only pointers to dynamically allocated objects on the memory heap."* It's more than that. You must only construct `shared_ptr`s with pointers to object that the `shared_ptr` will own. That means you can't have can't pass a pointer to something that a different `shared_ptr` or a `unique_ptr` already owns, even though it's allocated on the heap.

Comment: besides ``network`` who owns the shared pointers to the ``SharedEditor`` objects?